# horizontal plot of confidence interval and values in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, confidence-interval

I am working with Python with matplotlib and I would like to be able to plot values compared to given confidence interval so it would be easy to read.

Suppose I have the data:

```
labelstr = [ 'name1','name2','name3' ] 
values = [ 2.1, 40.5, 10.9 ]
lower_bound =  [ 1.8, 38.9 , 10.2 ]
upper_bound =  [ 2.3, 43.8 , 10.7 ]
```

I would like to plot the values with the corresponding confidence interval to show whether the value belongs or not. I am looking for a way to show the results horizontally. Ideally mark the point in a color if they belong and in a different color if they don't.

I would also like the show the values for the points and the lower and upper bounds inside the plot.

Something in as in this example would convenient https://blog.uvm.edu/tbplante/2018/03/14/code-to-make-a-dot-and-95-confidence-interval-figure-in-stata/

any suggestions? thank you

Comment: Can you provide a drawing? Why do you have 3 times name1? Do you want something the boxplots?

Comment: Sorry I corrected the names. Best example I can find is in https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html if you type "ax = sns.pointplot(x="tip", y="day", data=tips, join=False)"

Comment: I edited the post, changed a few things and gave an example of what I am trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've already got aggregated values and bounds, use [`Axes.errorbar`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.errorbar.html) which accepts `xerr` for horizontal errors:

> **shape(2, N):** Separate lower and upper values for each bar. First row contains the lower errors, the second row contains the upper errors.
> <sub>*Note that all error arrays should have* positive *values.*</sub>

1. Convert the bounds to relative errors of shape 2xN:

   ```py
   xerr = [
       [value-lower for value, lower in zip(values, lower_bound)],
       [upper-value for value, upper in zip(values, upper_bound)],
   ]

   # [[0.30000000000000004, 1.6000000000000014, 0.7000000000000011],
   #  [0.19999999999999973, 3.299999999999997, -0.20000000000000107]]
   ```

   <sup>Note that when the documentation says these values should be positive, it assumes all your values fall within the bounds. In your example, 10.9 falls outside the upper bound of 10.7, so the negative value is expected and should stay negative.</sup>
2. Use [`numpy.any`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) and [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) (or list comprehension) to generate a color array (orange if `xerr` is negative, else green):

   ```py
   import numpy as np

   inbounds = np.any(np.array(xerr) < 0, axis=0)
   colors = np.where(inbounds, 'orange', 'green')

   # array(['green', 'green', 'orange'], dtype='<U8')
   ```
3. Plot the values with [`Axes.scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html), errors with [`Axes.errorbar`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.errorbar.html), and labels with [`Axes.annotate`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate.html):

   ```py
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

   fig, ax = plt.subplots()
   ax.scatter(values, labelstr, c=colors, s=30, marker='|')
   ax.set_ylim(-0.5, len(labelstr) - 0.5) # add some vertical padding
   ax.set_xticks([])

   ax.errorbar(values, labelstr, xerr=xerr,
       fmt='none',     # don't connect data points
       ecolor='black', # color of error lines
       elinewidth=1,   # width of error lines
       capsize=4,      # length of error caps
       zorder=-1,      # put error bars behind scatter points
   )

   for value, lower, upper, label, color in zip(values, lower_bound, upper_bound, labelstr, colors):
       shared = dict(xy=(value, label), color=color, textcoords='offset points', ha='center')
       ax.annotate(value, xytext=(0, 5), va='bottom', **shared)
       ax.annotate(f'[{lower}, {upper}]', xytext=(0, -5), va='top', **shared)
   ```

   [image: scatter with horizontal error bars]

Comment: How can I add the values for the point and the upper/lower bounds on the plot?

Comment: @cinelli88 updated with color coding and annotations

Comment: Amazing thank you. One last question, now that I don't need the x axis labels, I tried fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.set_xticklabels([]) to remove them but it's not working

Comment: @cinelli88 if i understand correctly, you can use `ax.set_xticks([])`. i also updated the code to use the `fig, ax` notation

Comment: how did you declare ax?

Comment: `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` (it's in the updated answer -- refresh if you don't see it yet)